# How to like My friend's wall post with my android application?

Tags: android, facebook, comments, share, facebook-like

I am creating an android application , Where I want to like on my friend's wall post. Is it possible via my own android application ? I have tried this way but always a permission error like

```
{"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires publish_stream permission or Requires valid signature","type":"OAuthException","code":200}},
```

The sample of my application is

```
Utility.fb = new Facebook(StaticValues.APP_ID);
AsyncFacebookRunner fbAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(Utility.fb);
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
fbAsyncRunner.request(commentId + "/likes", parameters, "POST", new  MyRequestListener(), "");
```

I have added some permission like

```
 "offline_access", "publish_stream",
        "read_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins",  "photo_upload","user_likes","friends_likes"
```

How do I Like,comment,post under my friend's comments ?

Comment: Your _title_ is a little misleading. You want to know how to like comments on posts. The title suggests, you want to know how to like _the posts_.

Answer (score 0):

> "publish_stream"
>
> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's
>   stream and to the streams of the user's friends. This is a superset
>   publishing permission which also includes publish_actions

This permission is ok but I think problem may be that you are adding it only at  mobile end , i.e. , only in code. Add the permissions in your Facebook app which you registered at Facebook and try.